# Magento Product Ranges

Tags: products, collection

Is there any way in Magento to set up product ranges or collections?

For example, if my store sells clothing such as coats, jackets and shoes and I launch an Autumn range, is there a way to see other products in this range and also a page on the Autumn range?

I was thinking of using the manufacturer feature and changing references from "manufacturer" to "collection" or "range" but wondered if there was a more sensible way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to use Landing Pages. It can be either Magento module from the connect,  or just a CMS Page with the featured products block.  Where featured products are items filtered by the "collection" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use attributes, that's the exact reason for them. Once you enable layered navigation for a category, you can easily filter the results by attribute to give you a filtered subset of a given category.

Do not create a category for this purpose, catorgies are for categorisation, attributes are for exactly this purpose.

What you are looking for is wholly native to Magento.